# How to disable Google fonts and other things like that?

Tags: theming

How do I configure my theme or Drupal itself from fetching data such as Google fonts or anything like that? Also some JS files that get transferred as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ex: if the theme is called "cooltheme"

You need to go to drupal/sites/all/themes/cooltheme

and edit the **cooltheme.info** file

you should see something like this inside:

`scripts[] = js/main.js`  <-- so just delete this so it won't load it.

Then go to drupal/sites/all/themes/cooltheme/js and delete the .js file from here too.

For the fetching data from google fonts, they might be inside the .css file of the theme.